# Enumerated list with custom label, containing aligned math equations

Tags: equations, lists, align

[image]

How do I write `4°`? When I use `align*` or any other environment the equations become centered and I want all of them to be in a fine line just like on the picture.

Here is what I tried:

```
$(i)$ $\Delta^m(\Delta^n x(t))=\Delta^n(\Delta^m x(t))=\Delta^{n+m}x(t)$\\
$(ii)$ $\Delta(cx(t))=c\Delta x(t)$\\
$(iii)$ $\Delta(x(t)+y(t))=\Delta x(t)+\Delta y(t)$\\
$(iv)$ 
      \begin{align*}
      \Delta(x(t)y(t))&= y(t)\Delta x(t)+Ex(t)\Delta y(t)\\
       &= x(t)\Delta y(t)+Ey(t)\Delta x(t)\\
       &= x(t)\Delta y(t)+y(t)\Delta x(t)+\Delta x(t)\Delta y(t)
       \end{align*}\\
 $(v)$ $\Delta\left(\dfrac{x(t)}{y(t)}\right)=
       \dfrac{y(t)\Delta x(t)-      x(t)\Delta y(t)}{y(t)\cdot Ey(t)}$
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non)-working example code?

Comment: Do you tell `align` where to align your equations with `&`?

Comment: I don't think so. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you load (a) the `enumitem` package to create a custom environment for enumerated items and (b) the `amsmath` package to employ an `aligned` environment in the fourth item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label*=\upshape\arabic*\textsuperscript{o}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}
\item $\Delta^m(\Delta^n x(t))=\Delta^n(\Delta^m x(t))=\Delta^{n+m}x(t)$
\item $\Delta(cx(t))=c\Delta x(t)$
\item $\Delta(x(t)+y(t))=\Delta x(t)+\Delta y(t)$
\item $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
      \Delta(x(t)y(t))&= y(t)\Delta x(t)+Ex(t)\Delta y(t)\\
       &= x(t)\Delta y(t)+Ey(t)\Delta x(t)\\
       &= x(t)\Delta y(t)+y(t)\Delta x(t)+\Delta x(t)\Delta y(t)
       \end{aligned}$
\item $\displaystyle\Delta\left(\dfrac{x(t)}{y(t)}\right)=
       \dfrac{y(t)\Delta x(t)-      x(t)\Delta y(t)}{y(t)\cdot Ey(t)}$ 
\end{myenum}
\end{document}
```